# Compiling on Lion --clang

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm

Can someone either explain or preferably point me toward some documentation that explains the difference between passing --clang and not passing it to the gcc compiler.

I've had to append this parameter on numerous packages when compiling and I don't know what it does, I have yet to personally encounter code that won't compile without it but other projects seem to require it. I can not find it in the man docs for gcc, so I am trying to find a little bit more about what it is, all I know is that it has to do with the LLVM.

Comment: I think your `gcc` is atucally [llvmc](http://llvm.org/cmds/llvmc.html#clang).

Comment: Yes, `gcc` is likely a symlink to `llvm-gcc`? This is the clang backend, gcc front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no --clang option to anything. clang is another compiler for OS X and is available inside Xcode as "clang". It's another compiler similar to gcc, and is the new default compiler for OS X.

A link from the [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#llvm-compiler) explains more.